# bleeding-edge libraries and precompiled headers sizes

Tags: gcc, build-process, compilation, ramdisk, pch

Q1: My GCC precompiled header takes up 150 mb -- yes I'm using obscure TMP libraries from Boost. Anyone have any tips of benefiting from a PCH this large ? any makefile snippets which I could use to create a ram-disk(tmpfs) or something (transparently / on the fly) ?

Q2: Is there some way I could daemonize GCC ? -- after all if it stays active it doesn't have to reload the PCH everytime

Q3: (a) Will C++0x cut down on this issue by any specific improvements to enable better representions of TMP programs, (b) Or perhaps CLANG will bring about a change to the compilation process ?

p.s., MSVCC does a lot better of this then GCC.

p.s.s., I have a sneaking suspicion that GCC is not picking up my PCH.

Comment: After the first compilation, the OS will cache this in memory almost certainly, so I expect a ramdisk wouldn't buy you much.

Comment: I've heard of this idea of a "reactive compiler" which is more like how Intellisense works now -- basically it's just a daemon maintaining a huge dependency graph that intelligently recompiles just enough whenever you save the source file. Would love that on a big project! But as far as I know there aren't any implementations out there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Q1, I think OS cache should help you, don't see how you could improve it much otherwise (as j_random_hacker says).

Regarding Q2, what you want is currently in "project" stage for GCC, under the name of [Incremental Compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/IncrementalCompiler). You could ask Tom Tromey (his e-mail is on the linked page) what's the current status.

Comment: The OS cache doesn't seem to help in my case -- it takes as long with,or without the PCH's presence -- perhaps GCC isn't picking up the PCH -- I will do some more investigation.